# Google authenticator code not matching

Tags: c#, android

I am using  Google authenticator for 2 step verification. it's working fine in locally.In production code not matching.Because My server  and my mobile time zone not matching. How do i synchronize my server time zone to my mobile app.I am using time based code.

**calling function IsValid(secretcode, password)**

my code

```
public static class TimeBasedOneTimePassword
{
    public static readonly DateTime UNIX_EPOCH = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    private static MemoryCache _cache;

    static TimeBasedOneTimePassword()
    {
        _cache = new MemoryCache("TimeBasedOneTimePassword");
    }

    public static string GetPassword(string secret)
    {
        return GetPassword(secret, GetCurrentCounter());
    }

    public static string GetPassword(string secret, DateTime epoch, int timeStep)
    {
        long counter = GetCurrentCounter(DateTime.UtcNow, epoch, timeStep);

        return GetPassword(secret, counter);
    }

    public static string GetPassword(string secret, DateTime now, DateTime epoch, int timeStep, int digits)
    {
        long counter = GetCurrentCounter(now, epoch, timeStep);

        return GetPassword(secret, counter, digits);
    }

    private static string GetPassword(string secret, long counter, int digits = 6)
    {
        return HashedOneTimePassword.GeneratePassword(secret, counter, digits);
    }

    private static long GetCurrentCounter()
    {
        return GetCurrentCounter(DateTime.UtcNow, UNIX_EPOCH, 30);
    }

    private static long GetCurrentCounter(DateTime now, DateTime epoch, int timeStep)
    {
        return (long)(now - epoch).TotalSeconds / timeStep;
    }

    public static bool IsValid(string secret, string password, int checkAdjacentIntervals = 1)
    {
        string cache_key = string.Format("{0}_{1}", secret, password);

        if (_cache.Contains(cache_key))
        {
            throw new OneTimePasswordException("You cannot use the same secret/iterationNumber combination more than once.");
        }

        _cache.Add(cache_key, cache_key, new CacheItemPolicy { SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2) });

        string strpass = GetPassword(secret);
        if (password ==strpass )
            return true;

        for (int i = 1; i <= checkAdjacentIntervals; i++)
        {
            if (password == GetPassword(secret, GetCurrentCounter() + i))
                return true;

            if (password == GetPassword(secret, GetCurrentCounter() - i))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks,

SOMU

Comment: I haven't looked at the authenticator API, but I would *expect* all time stamps to just be sent in UTC. You really don't want to have to be in the same time zone as anything else. Can you show us your code?

Comment: Yes I am using UTC time only.When I am checking locally system time and mobile time not matched.that time code not working.after that i have changed mobile time it's working fine. but my server time and my time 10 hours diff. I have updated my code.

Comment: If you're using UTC on both client and server, then the problem is *not* the time zone. The server UTC time and your UTC time should be at least pretty much in sync. Do you have a link to the documentation for what the client will be sending? (I'm slightly suspicious of the division by 30, although it could be fine...)

Comment: what documentation you want. I have checked UTC time in local and server. it's showing 4 min diff.

Comment: Then that's probably the problem - it looks like you're only coping with it being up to 30 seconds out by default. If you specify 10 for `checkAdjacentIntervals` when you call it then it should cope with being up to 5 minutes out, if I've understood the code correctly.

Comment: Yes I added **checkadjacentIntervals**. It's working fine. Thank you so much ...